# Is it possible to increase the Kudo Local Usage?

Tags: azure-functions, kudu

I have a application service (NOT Functions) that in Kudu it shows `d:\local usage: 819,200 MB total; 742,708 MB free` and in another application (Functions) is shows `d:\local usage: 500 MB total; 36 MB free`.

Once in a while when I deploy the Functions project, it crashes giving me the follow message `There is not enough space on the disk`. When I go to Kudu I have `d:\local usage: 500 MB total; 0 MB free`.

I'm not sure if this 500 MB it's normal and I'm doing something wrong, or, if it's just something configurable, if so, where can I fix this?

---

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/3196

Answer (score 0):

For azure function and web app, computing resources are allocated according to the specifications of the plan on which it is based. If you need to increase the maximum limit, do this:

[image]

If you use rest api to check the limit, you will find it is more than before after scale up:

Before change:

[image]

After change:

[image]

Comment: `D:\home usage: 5,242,880 MB total; 5,241,329 MB free`, `d:\local usage: 500 MB total; 462 MB free`, but the problem is only on `d:\local usage`